# Refreshing the page properly after form submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, refresh

I have a form in html which has an action that executes another page.

however I need that new page to load properly in order for the script to function correctly.

I could do refresh onload however my page could take up to more than 30 secs to load therefore the time would be way too long.

Do you know how I could load the page properly when submitting a form?

Thanks

Comment: 30 secs to load a page? OMG

Comment: Yup I dont know why it involves a lot of backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this Page [**Reloading the page**](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/reload.html)

Use this code .

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeoutPeriod);
```

otherwise add this code.

```
$('#PageRefresh').click(function() {

              location.reload(true);

    });
```

Comment: my page can take a long time to reload, I want to load it completely when I first load it, not refresh after It has loaded.

Comment: @Joe: Hey joe joking ah??

Comment: @KessaVan:  I have a form, I click submit, I want the page to truly load correctly, I dont want to refresh the page, is that possible without refresh?

Comment: @Joe : GO through this link which will be useful for you, page loads without refreshing..http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?35337-Load-a-page-without-refreshing

Comment: I will just have to refresh the page like you said, I dont think there is  a way to truly load a page when a user submits a form